# Kibana Tophits on transform group by a field not all field

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana, kibana-7

So I have this case where I need to use top hits on transformation
I want to show data based on

### I have this data

```
email      col2      col3     col4  col5    Time
a.com         a        a        a    a     11:00 
a.com         a        a        a    a     11:01 
a.com         a        b        a    a     11:02
```

I want to remove the duplicate email, and only show it based on the latest time. I'm using transform and aggregate it based on max time. and for the group by I choose every field I needed. It returns data such as :
I transform the index and make it groupby : email, col2,col3,col4 and aggregate it by max(Time)

### Current index

```
email      col2      col3     col4  col5    Time
a.com         a        a        a    a     11:01 
a.com         a        b        a    a     11:02
```

### I only want it to show data
my target

```
email      col2      col3     col4  col5    Time
a.com         a        b        a    a     11:02
```

How can I make the transform based on groupby email only instead every field? Since I need all the field but I don't think add all of the as group by is right but there are only 2 methods either aggregation or groupby

my transformation definition :
It didn't come as what i need

```
{
  "id": "transform_baru",
  "source": {
    "index": [
      "email-profile-nov-bug*"
    ],
    "query": {
      "match_all": {}
    }
  },
  "dest": {
    "index": "transform_baru"
  },
  "pivot": {
    "group_by": {
      "Email.keyword": {
        "terms": {
          "field": "Email.keyword"
        }
      },
      "fa.keyword": {
        "terms": {
          "field": "fa.keyword"
        }
      },
      "ever.keyword": {
        "terms": {
          "field": "ever.keyword"
        }
      },
      "bln.keyword": {
        "terms": {
          "field": "bln.keyword"
        }
      },
      "domain.keyword": {
        "terms": {
          "field": "domain.keyword"
        }
      },
      "Email_age_category.keyword": {
        "terms": {
          "field": "Email_age_category.keyword"
        }
      },
      "Status_Category.keyword": {
        "terms": {
          "field": "Status_Category.keyword"
        }
      },
      "Vintage_cat.keyword": {
        "terms": {
          "field": "Vintage_cat.keyword"
        }
      }
    },
    "aggregations": {
      "extract_date.max": {
        "max": {
          "field": "extract_date"
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "settings": {},
  "version": "7.8.0",
  "create_time": 1607832008196
}
```

Comment: So, if I got this right, you need to group by email (because you don't want duplicate data from the same email), you need to take the document with that email and with the latest timestamp. From that document you need fields col2, col3 and col4? Am I correct?

Comment: Dear Val, Yes you right.. Actually if it possible I want it to be grouped by multiple field. Group by: Email, Bln
Aggregate : Max(Time)
and i want to show rest of the field

Comment: Also, can you show your [transform](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/transforms.html) definition?

Comment: Dear @Val, pardon me but I don't understand what you mean by transform definition. I did it by going to Stack management > Transforms > Create transforms. Please  kindly explain more to me. Thank you

Comment: Yes, so can you show the JSON definition of your transform?

Comment: Dear Val, I've added it above. It was false anyway and not meet what I want it to be.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem solved by using this [Tophit workaround](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/7.10/transform-painless-examples.html#painless-top-hits)
But I wasn't able to use it. Here is how to use it:

1. Choose only the groupby you need. In my case I would just add Email
2. Edit json config and add the aggregation with the latest_doc script
3. Change '@timestamp' field as your time field.
4. So technically, you **only** use email as groupby, and latest_doc as aggregation
5. On the preview, it might be show only the field that you choose as group by, but when the transform index created rest of the field will be show under latest.doc script. So don't worry and just create the transform

I hope this will help some elastic newbie to use this workaround.

Thank you for everyone who try to help me. Cheers